# SQL GROUP BY with subquery

Tags: sql

OrderHistory 
Id , IdOrder , State

and a table Order 
OrderId , ConfirmationDate , LastState

OrderHistory Example

```
1, 1000, 50
2, 1000, 60
3, 1000, 90
4, 1001, 50
5, 1001, 90
```

Order

```
1000, '2018-03-01', 90
1001, '2018-03-01', 90
```

I would take all order which doesn't never passed in state 60.
I tried with many query but i still get order by state 60.

```
SELECT oh.idOrdine  
FROM OrderHistory  oh 
where oh.state not in (60) 
and oh.OrderId in (Select OrderID 
                   From Orders 
                   where ConfirmationDate >= '2017-03-01' 
                     and state= 90) 
group by oh.OrderId 
order by oh.OrderId desc


SELECT * 
FROM Orders o 
  join OrderHistory oh on oh.OrderId = o.ORderId 
where o.ConfirmationDate>= '2017-03-01' 
  and o.state= 90 
  and oh.OrderId in (SELECT OrderId 
                     from OrderHistory 
                     WHERE State not in (60) 
                       and State in (95) 
                     group by ORderID)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Replace `not in` operator with `<>` comparison operator... hope this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `not in` , you should use `Not Exists`. By using Not in, you just eliminate that one row, and not all rows for that OrderID.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders o 
  join OrderHistory oh on oh.OrderId = o.ORderId 
  where o.ConfirmationDate>= '2017-03-01' 
  and o.state= 90 
  and oh.OrderId in (SELECT oh1.OrderId 
                     from OrderHistory oh1
                     WHERE Not Exists (select *
                                       From OrderHistory oh2
                                       where oh2.OrderId=oh1.OrderId and 
                                       oh2.State=60)
                      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
select o.*
from Orders o
where not exists (select 1 from OrderHistory oh where oh.OrderId = o.OrderId and oh.State = 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want orders that have had some state, then you can also use `group by` and `having`:

```
select oh.orderid
from orderhistory oh
group by oh.orderid
having sum(case when state = 60 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```